# HTML content loaded via AJAX loads external JavaScript out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's the scenario, not sure what I'm missing.

- Page A.htm makes an ajax request for page B.htm, and inserts the response into the page.
- Page B.htm contains links to several other JS files, many of which contain a document.ready() function to initialize them.

This works fine when A.htm and B.htm are on the same server but not when they are on different servers.

What I *think* I'm seeing here, is that when page A and B are on different servers (cross domain ajax), the external resources are being returned asynchronously, or at least out of order, so scripts are executing expecting JQuery.UI to be loaded already, when it is not.

Appreciate any pointers or advice. Apologies for the poor explanation.

Comment: Haven't used jQuery in some time, but doesn't .ajax return a promise?  can you call .done(second ajax request) to ensure they are returned in the correct order?  Something like: $.ajax().done(function(data){ if (data) {$.ajax()} )

Comment: There is no second ajax request.  At least not yet -- we need those external resources to load up properly first! :)

Comment: Okay.  But would something like this work? $.ajax(some request).done(function(data){ do second task}).  Basically wait for the returned scripts before moving forward with anything else?  Sorry, if I'm misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: Easy to misunderstand.  There is no second task in A.htm, it wants to load B.htm and the external scripts contain the next tasks...  but they can't fire because they try to fire out of order.  $ is undefined because jquery.min.js did not load before my.module.js tried to use it.

Comment: I am guessing that the order of execution of JavaScript files is not guaranteed when you inject them inside DOM. A smaller JS file might load and execute before a larger JS file. I'll see if I could find a concrete reference.

Comment: That's a good guess -- but odd how everything works fine when they are on the same server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are injecting HTML + script tags via jQuery. In this case *:

- HTML content except scripts are injected in the document
- Then all scripts are executed one by one
- If a script is external then it is downloaded and executed asynchronously

Therefore an external or inline script that depends on jQuery UI might execute before jQuery UI.

One possible solution is to change the way your pages work:

- Get rid of external scripts in pageb.html but keep inline scripts
- Load the required scripts in pagea.html
- Load pageb.html

Another solution is to roll your own jQuery function that will:

- Strip all `<script src>` elements from HTML
- Download and execute those scripts in order
- Inject the remaining HTML

---

<sup>* The exact behavior is not documented. I had to look into the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js) to infer the details.</sup>

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I have a mess on my hands here :)  I'm hoping that JAWR bundling everything into a single file will help smooth things over somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct in your impression that the issue is a difference in how the requests are handled cross-domain.

Here is a link to get you on the right track : [How to make synchronous JSONP crossdomain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780750/how-to-make-synchronous-jsonp-crossdomain-call)

However, you will have to actually re-achitect your solution somewhat to check if the resource has been loaded before moving on.  There are many solutions (see the link)

You can set a timer interval and check for something in the dom, or another reasonable solution (despite it's lack of efficiency) is to create a "proxy" serverside (eg php) file on your server and have that file do the cross-domain request, then spit out the result.

Note that since jquery UI is a rather large file, it's conceivable that the cross-domain request finishes first, and executes immediately, even though jqueryUI is not loaded yet.   In any case, you're going to have to start thinking about having your app react rather than follow a sequence.