# Making synchonous cross domain call to JSONP URI in MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, jsonp

I am new to MVC in javascript, and I am trying to implement MVC using different classes called Model, View and Data. I am also calling jsonp data using ajax call in my model class but as ajax call to jsonp is asynchronous I am not able to pass my model class object to View, I tried to call jsonp synchronously using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780750/how-to-make-synchronous-jsonp-crossdomain-call) link answer by "nnnnnn" but not able to understand where to put which code.. 
Please help.

Model class:

```
function Model()
{
    CountryName=[];
    CapitalName=[];
    SeqID=[];
    GeoPt=[];
    TelPref=[];
    isoN=[];
    CountryInfo=[];
}
Model.prototype.setData= function()
{

    function doMyAjaxCalls(callbackFunc) {
        var url='http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.jsonp';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) 
            {  
                callbackFunc(json);
            },
            error: function(e) 
            {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }); 
    }

    doMyAjaxCalls(function(json) {
    var arr=[];
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML="<tr><td> StatusMsg: "+json.StatusMsg+"</td><td> StatusCode: "+json.StatusCode+"</td><tr>";
                $.each(json.Results, function(i, object) {
                    $.each(object, function(property, value) {
                    if(property=="Capital")
                    {
                        if(value==null)
                        {
                            arr.push("-");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.each(value, function(subproperty, subvalue) {
                            if(subproperty=="Name")
                                arr.push(subvalue);
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    else if(property=="CountryCodes")
                    {
                        if(value==null)
                        {
                            arr.push("-");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.each(value, function(subproperty, subvalue) {
                            if(subproperty=="isoN")
                                arr.push(subvalue);
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        arr.push(value);
                    });
                    CountryName.push(arr[0]);
                    CapitalName.push(arr[1]);
                    SeqID.push(arr[3]);
                    GeoPt.push(arr[4]);
                    TelPref.push(arr[5]);
                    isoN.push(arr[6]);
                    CountryInfo.push(arr[7]);
                    arr=[];
                });
});
}
```

Controller Class:

```
function Controller () {
        return this;
    };
    Controller.prototype.load = function () {
        var model = new Model();
        model.setData();
        var view = new View(model);
        view.show();
    };
```

View Class:

```
function View(model) 
{
    this.model = model;
    _this=this.model;
    return this;
};
View.prototype.show = function () 
{
    counter=1;
    for(var i=0;i<241;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainTable").innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+counter+"</td><td>"+_this.CapitalName[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.CapitalName[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.SeqID[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.GeoPt[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.TelPref[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.isoN[i]+"</td><td>"+this.model.CountryInfo[i]+"</td><td><input type=\"button\" value=\"edit\"></input></td><tr>";
        counter++
    }
}
```

it gives error in View class

> View.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: You don't have `CapitalName` in your `View`, that's why you getting this error. Your model also looks wrong. You should define `class` properties via `this.prop = 'foo'`, not just `CountryName=[];`. You creating global vars this way, not object properties. So in your case it should be `this.countryName=[]` etc.

Comment: ok, i'll do that..Thanks