# async : false not working with Datatype : jsonp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one issue :

Call the ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "www.testwebsite.com",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async : false, 
        data: {
        Query: querykeyword,
        Market: "en-us"
        },
        success: callback
    });
```

When I use jsonp then async: false not work and if i remove jsonp then it will occur error like: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Would you please let me know the solution for the above problem.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make synchronous JSONP crossdomain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780750/how-to-make-synchronous-jsonp-crossdomain-call)

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) - What you **should** do is investigate why you require a synchronous ajax call - fix it and use an asynchronous one.

Comment: Possible duplicato of [asyncfalse-option-not-working-in-ajax-is-it-depreciated-in-jquery-1-8-fo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267969/asyncfalse-option-not-working-in-ajax-is-it-depreciated-in-jquery-1-8-fo)

Comment: The endpoint may also not support jsonp requests.  There's a lot we don't know.

Comment: Hello @Xatenev

I call the ajax via function and function call from for loop so for loop is done before the ajax return any value that's why i need to use async : false.

Comment: No you don't. There are [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to help with this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Would you please give me the exmaple for the same.